# vs 2008 and windows phone

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Cain i develop windows phone application with vs 2008 sp1?

Comment: Which windows phone version are you talking about?

Comment: In that case, JaredPars answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.  Developing for WP7 is only available on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Can i disable wpf interface on vs 2010, because i have graphic card with 64mb :S

Comment: @kenom, no you can't disable WPF because it's what the UI is written in.  You can disable aero in Windows which reduces the burden of WPF on a graphics card IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Studio 2010 is required. If you do not already have it, you can download [Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630878%28v=VS.92%29).